# Subtracting a year with DATEADD doesn't handle leap years correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, leap-year

While subtracting a year form current date, if current day is `February 28 2013` then below statement returns `February 28 2012`, but **correct** result should be `February 29 2012` as 2012 is a **leap** year. How can this scenario be handled.

```
SELECT DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Whether February 29 is the *correct* result is a question of interpretation.

Comment: As Pekka says, it's a matter of interpretation. Now, if you want the last day of the month, that's a different story...

Comment: Yeah. Do you want the last day of the month a year ago, the day 365 days ago, or the date 365/366 days ago depending on whether there's a leap day?

Comment: Either way, this is going to be relatively complex to 'push up the hill' in MySQL. I'd do the calc in my application, if possible.

Comment: I want to calculate exact a year difference, so in case of above scenario I should get 'February 29 2012'. 
If date was any other date for example 'February 26 2013' i should be getting  'February 26 2012' which works fine with this function SELECT DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())

Comment: @user2357759 - Substract one year taking leap years into account is exactly what your current code does. What you ask for looks like substracting 365 days (ignoring leap years).

Comment: Are you sure you use mySQL it looks like MS SQL Server T-sql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use this code **

```
SELECT DATE_SUB('2013-02-28', INTERVAL 365 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's something to think about...

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DAY(LAST_DAY('2012-02-28'))=29 THEN 'foo' ELSE 'bar' END x;
+------+
| x    |
+------+
| foo  |
+------+
1 row in set (1.22 sec)

SELECT CASE WHEN DAY(LAST_DAY('2013-02-28'))=29 THEN 'foo' ELSE 'bar' END x;
+------+
| x    |
+------+
| bar  |
+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your logic you should use case to process last day of the month in different way. If today is a last day of the month it will be the last day of the month one year ago.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LAST_DAY(CURDATE())=CURDATE()
            THEN LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) 
            ELSE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
       END
```

But what you will do if today is 29.02 ? WHAT day a year ago it should be? In this case for 28.02 and 29.02 you get the same 28.02 a year ago. What logic we should use here?